# In SQL DB2, how can I decypher a date string that can be either in YYYYMMDD or YYYYDDMM

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

##### Formal questions

1. I am looking for a way to get a date from a `varchar` column where values are sometimes formated as 'YYYYMMDD' and sometimes as 'YYYYDDMM'. I am well aware that 20210101 is ambiguous, but I have no means of correcting the data, therefore I made the arbitrary choice of favoring 'MMdd' over 'ddMM' whenever the two are possible. This first format seems indeed to be more abundant in the DB.
2. Can someone tell me how the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` behaves when it cannot convert a character string into a date? I expected a NULL value but this doesn't seem to be the case.

##### More into the details, and what I tried

I am working with a table where dates are coded as integers (20211231 standing for '2021-12-31'), which seems to be a rather classical encoding. My problem is that there seem to be little consistency in the encoding format : sometimes the month is in the middle (20211231) and sometimes it is at the end (20213112).

I actually discovered this fact while sketching my queries with squirrel and discovering that `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` would sometimes return an apparent NULL value.

As an example :

```
WITH mydates(d) AS (VALUES 20211231,20213112)
SELECT 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) AS dates
FROM mydates
```

results in

| dates |
| --- |
| 2021-12-31 |
| <null> |

I thus thought I might overcome the situation with something like

```
WITH mydates(d) AS (VALUES 20211231,20213112)
SELECT 
    COALESCE( DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')), DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYDDMM')), DATE('0001-01-01') ) AS dates
FROM mydates
```

or

```
with mydates(d) as (values 20211231,20213112)
SELECT (CASE WHEN d1 IS NULL THEN d2 ELSE d1 END) AS dates FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) AS d1 ,
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYDDMM')) AS d2
    FROM mydates
    ) tmp_dates
```

or

```
WITH mydates(d) AS (VALUES 20211231,20213112)
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) IS NULL THEN DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYDDMM')) ELSE DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) END) AS dates
FROM mydates
```

but all queries return the same results as the first one, except for the last one that simply wouldn't work and ends up with an error message.

I guess `TIMESTAP_FORMAT` doesn't really return a NULL value and I am clueless on both what value it returns on error, and how to solve the problem.

Comment: While I dont know db2, you are getting 2 rows from the 1st sql. You may consider excluding record with NULL such as `WITH mydates(d) AS (VALUES 20211231,20213112)
SELECT 
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) AS dates
FROM mydates WHERE dates is not null`. Also, you could use `NVL`. For example, `SELECT 
    NVL(DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(20211231),'YYYYMMDD')), DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(20213112),'YYYYMMDD')))`

Comment: NVL doesn't seem to be a regular scalar function on my system, but it looks like the COALESCE function : return first non null argument.
Thanks for the suggestion, but in my case it doesn't work because it looks like the TIMESTAMP_FUNCTION doesnt actually return a NULL value :/

Comment: @Benjaminschwarz . . . And what date is 20210201?  Is that in January or February?

Comment: @GordonLinoff : I am well aware of this problem. Since this seems to be the most represented format we decided to make the arbitrary choice of selecting MMdd over ddMM when the two make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can't
20210102 - January 2 or February 1?
20210510 - May 10 or October 5?
...

There's 12 days every month for which there's no way for you to determine which format the date is in.  That's 144 days out of 365.

You need to correct your data so that every date is in the same format.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this problem, although I didn't compute the area of ambiguity, thanks for pointing that out. 40% is indeed a lot !

Unfortunately data correction is not an option and therefore we made the arbitrary choice of favouring MMdd over ddMM since this format seems more abundent in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to circumvent the problem by checking the two central digits with something like :

```
WITH mydates(d) AS (VALUES 20211231,20213112)
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN INTEGER(SUBSTR(CHAR(d),5,2))<=12 THEN DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) ELSE  DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYDDMM')) END )
from mydates
```

Although this actually works in my case, the solution tastes bitter and I still don't know what happens with the fake null values.

Comment: I took a look at this problem on my system and run into the same issue.  It does seem that TIMESTAMP_FORMAT does not actually return null and instead returns some other invalid value.  I think Squirrel converts this to null when it sees it but the actual IBMi procedure returns something else.  I try running this in ACS and get a bunch of '+'s on an invalid value (something like '++++++++').  I don't really have a better solution for you than what you already came up with.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Moreover in the meantime I realized that although it produces a result, squirrel also returns an error code (SQLState:  01534 ErrorCode: 180) when it runs into a chain that cannot be formated through the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

STRSQL behaves differently than JDBC: refuses to execute sample query

```
    WITH mydates(d) AS (VALUES 20211231,20213112)
    SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(d),'YYYYMMDD')) AS dates
    FROM mydates
```

Query cannot be run.  See lower level messages.

> > CPF426B Function TIMESTAMP_FORMAT cannot be run.
> >
> > Function TIMESTAMP_FORMAT cannot be run for reason code 13
> >
> > 13 -- The timestamp string can not be interpreted by the format string
> > specified.